# Mongodb replacement for GROUP_CONCAT in mysql

Tags: mongodb-java

Dear All,
                
We have started using mongodb for our internal project. I am facing some issues and need your help.

Here is my table... books_issued

user_id    book_id
1                1
1                3
2                5
2                8

I want to list it using the $group and result should be like this...

user_id    book_id
1                        1,3
2                        5,8

We are using $match and $group. Please help to solve the same using java api.

Thanks,
Op

Comment: how are you using $match and $group?

Comment: Something similar to this...I have modified the actual one because there are some more conditions added.. [code]DBObject project = new BasicDBObject("$project", new BasicDBObject("userId", 1).append("bookId", 1);
DBObject group = new BasicDBObject("$group", new BasicDBObject("_id", "userId").append("b", "$bookId"));[code]

Comment: After searching I found using $group with $addToSet may be helpful here. Still waiting for reply or any clue that will give me my solution...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This query uses the user_id as _id field for the aggregate and adds the book_id to the books array:

```
db.books_issued.aggregate( {$group:  { _id: "$user_id", books: {$push: "$book_id"} } } )
```

The java code could look like:

```
    DBObject groupObj = new BasicDBObject().append("$group", 
            new BasicDBObject().append("_id", "$user_id")
            .append("books", new BasicDBObject("$push", "$book_id")));
    List<DBObject> pipeline = new ArrayList<DBObject>();
    pipeline.add(groupObj);
    AggregationOutput r = books.aggregate(pipeline);
```