# How do i perform this routine in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Have a collection with each document like

```
{ id: 1, user: { uid: 34, name: 'SDSDSD' } }
{ id: 2, user: { uid: 12, name: 'FHGJDF' } }
{ id: 3, user: { uid: 12, name: 'FHGJDF' } }
{ id: 4, user: { uid: 34, name: 'SDSDSD' } }
```

Want to have something like this in place of the above

```
{ uid: 12, content: { id: [2, 3] } }
{ uid: 34, content: { id: [1, 4] } }
```

Suggest with ways to go by this. Thank you.

Comment: May be this helpful for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24410424/mongodb-replacement-for-group-concat-in-mysql

Comment: try it `db.tbl_name.aggregate( {$group:  { uid: "$id", content: {$push: "$id"} } } )`

Comment: @TamilSelvan Kindly post your response as an answer.

Comment: ok. I posted as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Mongo Aggregation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/aggregation/)

Try

```
db.tbl_name.aggregate( {$group: { uid: "$id", content: {$push: "$id"} } } )
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [Mongo Aggregation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/aggregation/) to get expected output

If you are using mongoID '_id' to group then use

```
db.collection.aggregate({"$group":{"_id":"$user.uid","user_id":{"$push":"$_id"}}},
{$project:{"uid":"$_id","content":"$user_id","_id":0}})
```

If you want to use your own `id` to group then use (you just need to specify key in push)

```
 db.collection.aggregate({"$group":{"_id":"$user.uid","user_id":{"$push":"$id"}}},
{$project:{"uid":"$_id","content":"$user_id","_id":0}})
```